# Working with dynamic/anonymous objects and JSON.NET

Tags: dynamic, anonymous-types

.NET 4.0; VS 2010.

We're consuming a web service that does not offer a WSDL.  The data that is returned is not particularly complicated so we thought we would work with dynamic/anonymous types.  Here is an example of the JSON returned from one of the service methods (this string has been verified with JSONLint):
    [
    {
    "value": "AAA"
    },
    {
    "value": "BBB"
    },
    {
    "value": "CCC"
    },
    {
    "value": "DDD"
    },
    {
    "value": "EEE"
    },
    {
    "value": "FFF"
    }
    ]

Tried using:

```
 dynamic respDyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonStringAbove);
```

In this case, no errors are thrown, but in trying to access the resp variable, the Visual Studio debugger reports "The name 'resp' does not exist in the current context".

Tried LINQ next:

```
var respLinq = JObject.Parse(jsonStringAbove);
```

Which results in a runtime error: *Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1.*

Found [this article](https://json.codeplex.com/workitem/19226) that recommended different parsing methods depending on the format of the JSON:

```
if (jsonStringAbove.StartsWith("["))
{
   var arr = JArray.Parse(jsonStringAbove);
}
else
{
    var obj = JObject.Parse(jsonStringAbove);
}
```

When `var arr = JArray.Parse(jsonStringAbove);` is hit, the debugger simply exists the method and returns to the calling procedure.  No error is thrown.  If the leading and trailing square brackets are removed, another run time error similar to the results in the second example is encountered.

So. Not sure where to turn at this point.  Seems like what we're trying to do is very straightforward which make me think I'm missing something blatantly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but the solution to this was to declare my variables as fields within the class.  Variables that were local to the methods I was working with simply did not work.  Once declared as class-wide variables, the code behaved as expected.  Very odd.  I suspect that this problem may be specific to my VS environment and/or solution configuration as it does not appear to be occurring with anyone else.  Lucky me.